# Como guradar un grafico interactivo htlm a jpg, realizado con bipartiteD3 en R

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un grafico de tipo bipartite con el paquete bipartiteD3, obtengo como resultado un grafico interactivo que se abre en un navegador. Ese grafico por tanto esta en formato interactivo y necesito llevar ese grafico a una imagen.
Esta es mi base de datos en el siguiente enlace:
https://mega.nz/file/DShx1KTB#dqomR4G0sE4xDoYF0mUb3yHWYYx5OZaYJutGISG-a7A
Este es el script que estoy usando:

**

```
prueba <- sitios #sitios es mi base de data que esta en el enlace de mega
prueba1<- as.matrix(prueba)
prueba_df<-Matrix2DF(prueba1)
bipartite_D3(prueba_df,PrimaryLab='Donor', SecondaryLab = 'Recipient', SiteNames='ODA',
             MainFigSize = c(5800, 7500), 
             IndivFigSize = c(900, 3600),
             BoxLabPos = c(20, 20),
             PercPos = c(200,200),
             BarSize = 20,
             MinWidth = 5,
             Pad=5,
             PercentageDecimals = 2,
colouroption = 'brewer',BrewerPalette ='Dark2',
)
```

**

Gracias adelantada por la ayuda

Comment: Si incluyes los datos en tu pregunta tendrás más posibilidad de tener una respuesta, pues eso ayuda a las personas que desean ayudarte a replicar tu código. Puedes usar la función `dput()` sobre una parte o la totalidad de tus datos, según sea la extensión de ellos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, los datos están en el enlace de mega que compartí.  https://mega.nz/file/DShx1KTB#dqomR4G0sE4xDoYF0mUb3yHWYYx5OZaYJutGISG-a7A

Comment: Hola @Asiel Cabrera Guerrero: Links externos no son la mejor opción para garantizar la repetibilidad del código. Esto porque muchos links no son permanentes y al perderse el link, se pierde la opción de replicar el código y la posibilidad de ayudar a personas que en el futuro tengan dudas similares a la tuya. También, muchos usuarios evitan hacer click en links por motivos de seguridad informática. En el  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) hay más informaciones sobre repetibilidad del código.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción puede ser guardar el gráfico como html usando el paquete `htmlwidgets` y luego leer el archivo en R y guardarlo como gráfico usando el paquete `webshot`.

Acá un ejemplo con la documentación de la función bipartiteD3::bipartite_D3`:

```
testdata <- data.frame(
    higher = c("bee1","bee1","bee1","bee2","bee1","bee3"),
    lower = c("plant1","plant2","plant1","plant2","plant3","plant4"),
    webID = c("meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow"),
    freq=c(5,9,1,2,3,7))

SmallTestWeb <- bipartite::frame2webs(testdata,type.out="array")

bip2 <- bipartite_D3(SmallTestWeb, filename = 'demo1')

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(bip2, "plot.html")
webshot::webshot("plot.html", "plot.png")
```

Otra opción, si usas Rstudio es guardar la imagen desde el panel de visualización:

Viewer -> Export -> Save as image